# How to assign/bind a known function to a variable?

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ida

I wonder how to make a variable within IDA Pro bound to some function so the next time I double click the variable it will send me to the function.

```
v1 = this

*v2 = Known-Function
```

At Some Different location:

```
char __stdcall ClassA__KnownFunction(ClassA *ClassA, void a2) {

commands.....

}
```

I know you can set type to int, struct, dword etc. But I am looking for some method to point the variable to already known offset/function in IDA Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Function pointer is merely a variable that holds the address of a function; you cannot treat a variable like a constant. You have two options:

1. Add the name of the function as a comment (just for the sake of documentation).
2. Get rid of the variable assignment, hard-code the function address by editing the hex, and then perform the analysis again.

Comment: but hex edit will result changing my executable, i just want it for analyzing and getting closer to decomplied code

Comment: @atigertest You can use the built-in hex editor (which only modifies the database) without modifying the actual executable.

Comment: @atigertest if you add the name of the function as a comment and double-click on it it will actually take you to the function code.